# How do they change people to animal?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lobster

From the movie *The Lobster*, after certain days if they can't find the pair they will change them to animals. How do they change it?

Comment: Hello and welcome!   Are you asking how they did it by special effects or how they did it within the plot of the movie?  Maybe edit into your question what you're specifically asking for  :)

Comment: Plot of the movie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They get sent to the [transformation room](http://scriptfest.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/THE-LOBSTER.pdf).  Scene 60:

> And so he decided to turn her into  an animal. A hotel maid helped him
>   and he never understood why she did  it. I asked him many times what 
>   sort of animal he turned her into,  but he always gave the same
>   answer.  “That’s none of your concern”. That  night he left the hotel,
>   once and  for all.

An example of the [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouDoNOTWantToKnow)

Comment: Aside from mentioning the transformation room, the rest of your response doesn't relate to the OP's question.

Comment: @Charles So...downvote it, then.

Answer (score 1):

From a conversation between David and his two friends while at the hotel (roughly 30min into the film):

[image]

> THE LIMPING MAN: What they do, as soon as you enter the [transformation] room is to wash your body and head really well.
>
> LISPING MAN: How do you know?
>
> THE LIMPING MAN: My uncle used to know a waiter who worked here.
>
> LISPING MAN: No waiters know about the procedure. They're not allowed inside that room.
>
> THE LIMPING MAN: Nevertheless. They peel off the skin, which has become soft due to the water and the soap. Afterwards they remove the heart, the eyes, and other vital organs of the body with a laser or scalpels. Then the procedure changes according to the animal when it's chosen.
>
> DAVID: That makes total sense. I mean, I suppose mammals demand a different kind of work than fowls, for example.
>
> THE LIMPING MAN: Exactly. Afterwards they throw the remaining body parts into the casks outside the hotel's restaurant and distribute the blood to the hospitals in the city.

Assuming the description provided by The Limping Man is true, that's as much detail as the movie provides.

[image]